# Hyperledger Fabric Node.js Sdk got error :access denied

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-chaincode

I am getting the below-mentioned error.
I have set up a Hyperledger Fabric network which has 2 args, having a single peer each. I have created, installed, instantiated the chaincode inside the docker containers and they are working fine. I used the node.js SDK to enrol admin and register user(similar to fabcar). After successfully registering the user, I tried to connect to the channel (query.js). I am facing the error `Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied.` Please help me out to fix this issue.

**Error**

```
2020-07-30T20:02:58.852Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied 2020-07-30T20:02:58.853Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied 2020-07-30T20:02:58.853Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
```

**On navigating to peer logs I found**

```
2020-07-30 20:01:27.729 UTC [discovery] processQuery -> WARN 063 got query for channel mychannel from 172.21.0.1:39964 but it isn't eligible: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied
2020-07-30 20:01:27.729 UTC [discovery] processQuery -> WARN 064 got query for channel mychannel from 172.21.0.1:39964 but it isn't eligible: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied
2020-07-30 20:01:27.729 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 065 unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.1:39964 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=960.632µs.
```

**Order logs**

```
: go1.12.12
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-07-30 19:45:19.010 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 008 Beginning to serve requests
2020-07-30 19:49:35.018 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 009 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.6:47634 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=17.59346ms
2020-07-30 19:49:35.021 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 00a Getting block information from block storage
2020-07-30 19:49:35.131 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChain -> INFO 00b Created and starting new chain mychannel
2020-07-30 19:49:35.134 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00c streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.6:47632 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=140.497072ms
2020-07-30 19:53:41.978 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00d Error reading from 172.21.0.6:47718: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2020-07-30 19:53:41.978 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00e streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.6:47718 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=3.667041ms
2020-07-30 19:53:49.541 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.3:41404 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.734645ms
2020-07-30 19:56:07.720 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 010 Error reading from 172.21.0.6:47906: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2020-07-30 19:56:07.720 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 011 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.6:47906 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=5.159439458s
2020-07-30 20:00:15.785 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 012 Error reading from 172.21.0.6:48010: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
```

**Configtx.yaml**

```
Organizations:

- &ordererOrg
Name: Orderer
ID: OrdererMSP
MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/orderer.immume.com/msp

- &Org1
Name: Org1
ID: Org1MSP
MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.immume.com/msp
AnchorPeers:
- Host: peer0.org1.immume.com
Port: 7051

- &Org2
Name: Org2
ID: Org2MSP
MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.immume.com/msp
AnchorPeers:
- Host: peer0.org2.immume.com
Port: 8051


Capabilities:
Channel: &ChannelMyCapabilities
V1_3: true
Orderer: &OrderMyCapabilities
V1_1: true
Application: &ApplicationMyCapabilities
V1_3: true
V1_2: false
V1_1: false
Application: &ApplicationMyDefaults


Organizations:

Orderer: &OrdererMyDefault

OrdererType: solo
Addresses:
- orderer.orderer.immume.com:7050
BatchTimeout: 2s
BatchSize:
MaxMessageCount: 40
AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
PreferredMaxBytes: 4354 KB


Profiles:

myGenesisProfile:
Capabilities:
<<: *ChannelMyCapabilities
Orderer:
<<: *OrdererMyDefault
Organizations:
- *ordererOrg
Capabilities:
<<: *OrderMyCapabilities
Consortiums:
myconsortium:
Organizations:
- *Org1
- *Org2


mychannel:
Consortium: myconsortium
Application:
<<: *ApplicationMyDefaults
Organizations:
- *Org1
- *Org2
Capabilities:
<<: *ApplicationMyCapabilities

newchannel:
Consortium: myconsortium
Application:
<<: *ApplicationMyDefaults
Organizations:
- *Org1
- *Org2
Capabilities:
<<: *ApplicationMyCapabilities
```

I have also attached the screenshots for better reference of peer logs, order logs, query.js, connection.yaml, docker container invoke & query

[peer0](https://pasteboard.co/Jk5VDFU.png)

[peer0.org1 log](https://pasteboard.co/Jk5ShrU.png)

[ordderer logs](https://pasteboard.co/Jk5V383.png)

[configtx.yaml part 1](https://pasteboard.co/Jk60ZjC.png)

[configtx.yaml part 2](https://pasteboard.co/Jk60Ck3.png)

[query.js](https://pasteboard.co/Jk5SXFV.png)

[peer0 chaincode container invoke and query](https://pasteboard.co/Jk5TUEd.png)

[connection, yaml](https://pasteboard.co/Jk5UD7r.png)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't configured or you're not using discovery service, then disable it in file `query.js`.

Diable discovery service by setting `discovery: { enabled: false }` in statement `await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'appUser', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });`

Answer (score 0):

Use the service discovery options `"asLocalhost": false` in your query.js.
As the application is running outside of the blockchain networks.

And also change the url in the connection.yaml to the host-name of the container rather than as a localhost or 127.0.0.1.
For example like this:

```
  orderers:
    orderer.example.com:
      url: grpcs://orderer.example.com:7050               // like this
      grpcOptions:
       ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
      tlsCACerts:
        path:  ./caro-blockchain-commonfiles/config/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
  peers:
    peer0.org1.example.com:
      url: grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051                 // like this 
      grpcOptions:
        ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      tlsCACerts:
        path: ./caro-blockchain-commonfiles/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    peer0.org2.example.com:
      url: grpcs://peer0.org2.example.com:9051               // like this 
      grpcOptions:
        ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.example.com
      tlsCACerts:
        path: ./caro-blockchain-commonfiles/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp/cacerts/localhost-8054-ca-org2.pem
```

And at the end check for the application, is it in the same network as of Blockchain Services.

```
docker network connect networkNameBlockchain  containerNameOfApp
```